# ASP.NET VB Display new images at runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, runtime

In my VB project i already have functions in place for retrieving every image path in a specified directory, I then use

```
Dim Pics() As String = piccom.GetPictures("The\Dir")
For Each pic In Pics
    If Not pic = "" Then
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pic)
        Dim Width As Integer = bmp.Width
        Dim Height As Integer = bmp.Height

    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

to loop through all the returned images, thing is I need to be able to display these images at run time in the main content of the page, how can I display said images at runtime?

EDIT:
I went out on a whim and tried this

```
For Each pic In Pics
    If Not pic = "" Then
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pic)
        Dim Width As Integer = bmp.Width
        Dim Height As Integer = bmp.Height

        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
        bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Now this actually got me closer to what i want, but instead of displaying the page with the images nested in it it just streamed the first image it grabbed to my browser - not quite what i was after. I want all the images nested in the pre-existing content box on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working in the end, first I created a new page called 'image.aspx', and put this in it

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class image
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim query As String = Request.QueryString("i")
        Dim maxw As String = Request.QueryString("maxw")
        Dim maxh As String = Request.QueryString("maxh")
        If Not query = "" Then
            Dim file = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\DIRWHEREPICTURESARE" + query

            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(file)
            Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

I then created a repeater in my page, with an object template like so

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

    <ItemTemplate>            
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%#Container.DataItem%>"/><br />
    </ItemTemplate> 

</asp:Repeater>
```

and in the code behind put

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Pics() As String = piccom.GetPictures("Image\Directory")
    Dim aList = From fileName In Pics
    Repeater1.DataSource = aList
    Repeater1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Hope this helps anyone who runs into this problem!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   Dim Pics() As String = piccom.GetPictures("The\Dir")
    For Each pic In Pics
        If Not pic = "" Then
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pic)
            Dim Width As Integer = bmp.Width
            Dim Height As Integer = bmp.Height
            picImage.Image = bm
            picImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I dont want to change a pre-existing image box, I want to create a new one, so that ALL the images in the directory can be shown not just one.